# Why is linq reversing order in group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query which seems to be reversing one column of several in some rows of an earlier query:

```
        var dataSet = from fb in ds.Feedback_Answers
                         where fb.Feedback_Questions.Feedback_Questionnaires.QuestionnaireID == criteriaType
                            && fb.UpdatedDate >= dateFeedbackFrom && fb.UpdatedDate <= dateFeedbackTo
                         select new
                         {
                             fb.Feedback_Questions.Feedback_Questionnaires.QuestionnaireID,
                             fb.QuestionID,
                             fb.Feedback_Questions.Text,
                             fb.Answer,
                             fb.UpdatedBy
                         };
```

Gets the first dataset and is confirmed working.
This is then grouped like this:

```
var groupedSet = from row in dataSet
                         group row by row.UpdatedBy
                             into grp
                             select new
                             {
                                 Survey = grp.Key,
                                 QuestionID = grp.Select(i => i.QuestionID),
                                 Question = grp.Select(q => q.Text),
                                 Answer =  grp.Select(a => a.Answer)
                             };
```

While grouping, the resulting returnset (of type: string, list int, list string, list int) sometimes, but not always, turns the question order back to front, without inverting answer or questionID, which throws it off.
i.e. if the set is questionID 1,2,3 and question A,B,C it sometimes returns 1,2,3 and C,B,A

Can anyone advise why it may be doing this? Why only on the one column? Thanks!

edit: Got it thanks all! In case it helps anyone in future, here is the solution used:

```
        var groupedSet = from row in dataSet
                         group row by row.UpdatedBy
                             into grp 
                             select new
                             {
                                 Survey = grp.Key,
                                 QuestionID = grp.OrderBy(x=>x.QuestionID).Select(i => i.QuestionID),
                                 Question = grp.OrderBy(x=>x.QuestionID).Select(q => q.Text),
                                 Answer =  grp.OrderBy(x=>x.QuestionID).Select(a => a.Answer)
                             };
```

Comment: If you want data in a specific order, why not use `OrderBy` in the last query?

Comment: You havent even mentioned the LINQ provider. In Linq-To-Object the order will be preserved. If it's a database driven provider the database will determine the order. Since you haven't specified an ordering, it is free to return them in any order because tables don't have an inherent order.

Comment: The provider is linq to entity. I knew it didn't infer an order, but didn't think it would matter as I had thought it would be in the same relative order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reversal of a grouped order is a coincidence: `IQueryable<T>`'s `GroupBy` returns groups in no particular order. Unlike in-memory `GroupBy`, which specifies the order of its groups, queries performed in RDBMS depend on implementation:

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling `GroupBy<TSource,TKey,TElement>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>, Expression<Func<TSource,TElement>>)` depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter.`

If you would like to have your rows in a specific order, you need to add `OrderBy` to your query to force it.

> How I do it and maintain the relative list order, rather than apply an order to the resulting set?

One approach is to apply grouping to your data after bringing it into memory. Apply `ToList()` to `dataSet` at the end to bring data into memory. After that, the order of subsequent `GrouBy` query will be consistent with `dataSet`. A drawback is that the grouping is no longer done in RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm wondering how I do it and maintain the relative list order, rather than apply an order to the resulting set.  Essentially, when I am returning the object, the order of the resultset returned is irrelevant, so long as the order of the three internal lists remains consistent.

Comment: @David Please see the edit that suggests one approach to fixing the order.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it with a slightly different method, as in my question edit, but that is a really useful thing to know.